# Eclipse Kepler Java 8

Tags: eclipse, java-8

I want to start using Java 8 with Eclipse but I don't know how to install it - I can't find any tutorials on it. I am using Eclipse Kepler and have added a JRE for JDK 8 to the IDE but it won't let me continue to create the project because of a compliance problem with the JRE versions. How can I use Java 8 with the Eclipse Kepler IDE?

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027255/eclipse-java-8-support .  Without wanting to sound harsh, working with betas (both jdk and ide) is not for the faint of heart, if it's "just to have a look" you'd better wait.

Comment: February 2014: [Updated instructions below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21624103/6309).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Have a look at [this bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=380190) from time to time for progress on Java 8 in Eclipse's JDT.

EDIT: For Kepler you need SR2 (4.3.2) and the Java 8 [feature patch](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler). Starting with I20140318-0830 all [Luna (4.4) builds](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/) contain support for Java 8 "out-of-the-box". The final version of Eclipse Luna (4.4) will be released at the end of June 2014.

Comment: To use it with WTP (web development), you need to install the patch from http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/patches/drops/R3.5.2/P-3.5.2-20140329045715/repository to add the Java Facet version 1.8 (see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=430637)

Comment: Kepler+patch or Luna is better for Java 8 developer now?

Comment: If you fail to install the patch (calculating alternative solutions) notice the radio buttons - select the one that says you want to modify the installation - you will see what needs to be uninstalled - proceed at your discretion

Comment: Sigh.  This doesn't work.  "Will not be installed...Eclipse JDT...Patch with Java 8 support (for Kepler SR2)".  I am Kepler SR2.  Grrrr.

Comment: I would definitely recommend to use Luna now, that offers better Java 8 support in many ways.

Comment: Is there any option to install Kepler patch offline? download the patch as zip file...?

Answer (score 20):

Now, after Java 8 is released, there is a feature patch, but only for **Kepler SR2 (4.3.2)**. Installation via

Help > Install New Software... > 'Work with': http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3-P-builds/

see [Tutorial Installing Java 8 on Eclipse Kepler](http://www.bigdev.de/2014/03/tutorial-installing-java-8-support-for.html)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Followed those steps however it "can't perform the operation" and computes alternate solutions (15) giving the message *"Eclipse PDE (Plug-in Development Environment) Patch with Java 8 support (for Kepler SR2)" is not applicable to the current configuration and will not be installed"* But there is no problem with "Eclipse JDT". **I AM using Eclipse KEPLER 4.3.2**

Comment: @reubenjohn Your Eclipse probably doesn't have PDE installed, so it can't be patched. Since you don't already have it, you probably don't need it, so just uncheck PDE, select only the JDT patch and it will install fine.

Answer (score 8):

Early access builds of Eclipse with Java 8 support are available. Installation instruction can be found [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Core/Java8).

Comment: Answers that rely mostly on links are discouraged.

Answer (score 3):

[Wayne Beaton](http://waynebeaton.wordpress.com/about/) (Director of Open Source Projects at the [Eclipse Foundation](http://www.eclipse.org/)) just published (February 2014) an article on "[Building and Running Java 8 Support](http://waynebeaton.wordpress.com/2014/02/04/building-and-running-java-8-support/)" (with Eclipse Luna 4.4Mx).

It includes:

- Getting the [sources of JDK8](https://jdk8.java.net/)
- Downloading the [latest milestone of the Eclipse SDK](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/) (4.4Mx)
- Configuring the “`vm`” option in the `eclipse.ini` file to use the Java 8 JRE included with the downloaded JDK.
- Adding [Egit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/)
- Clone the `BETA_JAVA8` branch of the Git repo [JDT Core](https://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/jdt/eclipse.jdt.core.git), [JDT UI](https://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git) and [JDT Debug](https://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/jdt/eclipse.jdt.debug.git) repos.
- Using the handy “Import all projects” feature to automatically pull all the code into my workspace.
- Setting various JRE [1.4](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase14-419411.html), [5](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html) and [6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.htmlc).
- Putting the right mapping for those JRE in the [execution environment](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Execution_Environments).

---

For Eclipse Kepler 4.3+, [leeor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3166303/leeor) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619638/eclipse-kepler-java-8/21624103#comment33727560_21624103):

> As of Feb 21st, you can install the beta 8 JDT via "**`install new software...`**" in Eclipse (I use Kepler) here: [JDT/Eclipse Java 8 Support (BETA)](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_%28BETA%29)

```
http://build.eclipse.org/eclipse/builds/4P/siteDir/updates/4.3-P-builds
```

Comment: As of Feb 21st, you can install the beta 8 JDT via "install new software.." in eclipse (I use kepler) [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_(BETA))

Comment: @leeor Great. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: The update site made installation easy for me.  However, the Java 8 compiler in elclipse is producing stack overflows consistently once I change all my projects to build with Java 8.

Answer (score 2):

[Java8 support for Eclipse Kepler SR2](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-8-support-eclipse-kepler-sr2?mpc=true&mpc_state=) has been removed from eclipse marketplace. You can access the archive [here](https://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/P20140317-1600/). Download the zipped repo and install it as a local archive update site.

Answer (score 1):

URL : http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3-P-builds/

Add it like the screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have installed Java 8, JRE 8 and configured them (setting class paths etc.). 
Follow the steps.
Go to Help->Eclipse market place
In the search box type "java 8 kepler"
The first link that appears is Java 8 support for Kepler SR2
select it and install it.
It will take a few minutes.
You may need to restart Eclipse after completion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the version of Kepler your using might not have the support for Java8. You can either install the Java8 Patch from market place if your using SR2 version

or

You can directly download Eclipse Kepler SR2 from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/kepler/sr2), which comes with default support for Java8