# enable Java8 support in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

I have the newest Eclipse, but there is no support for Java8.

```
Version: Luna M6 Release (4.4.0M6)
Build id: 20140312-2027
```

Or maybe there is, but I have to enable it somehow. How to do it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse + Java 8 support?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027255/eclipse-java-8-support)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current build does not have Java 8 support. [This wiki page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_%28BETA%29) has the current status and links to the branch containing Java 8 support. I see it says that a GA version will be available on 18th March.