# Ubuntu Eclipse Compiler 1.8 does not appear

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, java

In Ubuntu, after installation of Openjdk 8, I applied the necessary changes in my Eclipse 3.8.1:

In preferences -> Java -> installed JREs, adding the related VM;

In Project -> Properties -> Java build path, updating JRE system library;

But, yet, in preferences -> Java -> compiler, I cannot see any compiler version more than 1.8.

What is the problem?

Comment: Does eclipse 3.8.1  support Java 8?

Comment: how should I check it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027255/eclipse-java-8-support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse support for Java 8 was from Kepler (4.3). You may need to move newer version of eclipse than your current version(3.8).

(update from  [Elliott Frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2970947)  )

Luna is the version after Kepler, and supports java 8 out of the box.
See https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Core/Java8

Comment: I suppose that, also, Luna supports 8 as I see in http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Comment: Luna is the version after Kepler, and supports java 8 out of the box. I believe you have to add support for java 8 as an optional update for Kepler. Earlier versions of eclipse don't support java 8.

Comment: Thanks @Elliott Frisch . I included it in the answer.  The duplicated question has much more info anyway)