# Java + Eclipse: The method computeIfAbsent(String, (<no type> k) -> {}) is undefined for the type

Tags: java, eclipse, priority-queue

I am using Eclipse (Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)) and encountering the following error: `The method putIfAbsent(String, new PriorityQueue<>()) is undefined for the type 
 Map<String,PriorityQueue<String>>`. Everything seems done correctly but still getting the error. What could I be missing?

```
Map<String, PriorityQueue<String>> targets = new HashMap<>();

...


for(String[] ticket: tickets) {
    targets.putIfAbsent(ticket[0], new PriorityQueue<>());
}
```

**EDIT**
Did the following, yet still getting the error

[image]

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Added Java 8 SE, yet still getting the error.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**EDIT 3**

[image]

Comment: Is `ticket` a `String[]` then?

Comment: `new PriorityQueue()` should be `new PriorityQueue<>()`

Comment: @4castle That would be a warning, not a compiler error.

Comment: @shmosel You're right. [I can't reproduce the problem.](https://ideone.com/RPBOIO)

Comment: Are you using Java 8? It may be that you have an older JDK installed, or your Eclipse isn't configured to use Java 8.

Comment: @4castle sorry but how can I check? Sorry but it was in a for loop, `for(String[] ticket: tickets) {...}`.

Comment: @4castle is right, this is clearly a language level issue, check your project config and make sure you are using JDK 1.8, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588537/how-to-change-jdk-version-for-an-eclipse-project

Comment: 1.7 is not 1.8, no?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse + Java 8 support?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15027255/5743988)

Comment: @RC. please take a look at the original post. Converted to 1.8 yet still have the error. What could I be missing?

Comment: @4castle Appreciate the lead and took a look at it, but it is for Kepler mainly. How can I do it for Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)?

Comment: `new PriorityQueue<String>()` with String. Seems you are in a required/inferred type pingpong.

Comment: @JoopEggen What do you mean?

Comment: I am not using eclipse at the moment, but I wondered using `<String>` instead of `<>` would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no method `Map#putIfAbsent(K key, V value)` in Java 7, but there's in Java 8. See:

- [Map (Java Platform SE 7)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)
- [Map (Java Platform SE 8)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

In your specific case, make sure the project properties under Eclipse (described below)  are set to Java 8. You can edit them by doing: *Right click on project > Properties*:

- Project properties > **Java Build Path**
- Project properties > **Java Comiler**

---

Here's a possible solution:

[image: Java Build Path]

If your Java Build Path is targeted to Java 7, follow the below steps to change it:

- Select *JRE System Library*
- Click button *Edit...* located on the right side
- Use one of the following options

  - Global: Workspace default JRE. Make sure it is set to Java 8
  - Local: Alternate JRE. Choose Java 8.

After setting this, you can continue to check the Java Complier.

[image: Java Complier - project settings]
[image: Java Complier - Eclipse settings]

Now, you should run your project without problem.

---

> Do I have to do this to each project individually or does it apply to all projects?

You don't have to do this for each project. You can have a set-up for all projects of this workspace.

To setup Java Runtime Environments for all the projects, you can check which JREs are installed and change the default one.

- Go to *Eclipse* > *Preferences...*
- Search `JRE`
- Check the installed JREs

  - If your recently installed JREs aren't appeared, then add them manually one by one using button *Add...*. Or add them automatically using the button *Search...*.
  - Select the default JRE that you want

As the screenshot shown: **By default, the checked JRE is added to the build path of newly created Java projects.** Now it should be OK for all the projects.

[image: Installed JREs]

To edit the JRE for a specific project, you can. Here're the steps to do it:

- Select the target project, right click > *Properties*
- Select *Java Build Path*
- Edit *JRE System Library*
- Choose your preferred JRE version from

  - Execution Environment
  - Alternate JRE
  - Workspace default JRE

Comment: What is the quickest way to convert it to Java 8?

Comment: please take a look at the original post. I converted to Java SE 8, yet I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I am using Eclipse Version: Neon Milestone 6 (4.6.0M6) and Java  1.8.0_111 and it seams works fine. To upgrade Eclipse save Projects (not fully Workspace - because new Eclipse will use new configuration of AppServer Java and so on.) -> Download new Version of Eclipse -> open Eclipse -> Import existing project into workspace :)))

Comment: @LyManeug, you did set the compiler to _1.8_, but in [your last image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zJZu.png), it shows that there's a warning _"When selecting 1.8 compilance, make sure the have a compatible JRE installed and activated **(currently 1.7)**"_. So your JRE is still 1.7. Try to configure it through the link "Configure..."

Comment: @Musa do you mind making an answer along with screenshots? Would really help!

Comment: @MincongHuang I updated the screenshot in the original post with the warning gone. Yet the error still shows. Did you test it out with Mars?

Comment: @LyManeug I uploaded the screenshot, please see the update. I'm not sure where does the problem locate. I used Eclipse Neon, but JDK version is really a basic setting, it has nothing to do with Eclipse version, e.g. Mars.

Comment: @MincongHuang Please take a look at the original post. Put a new screenshot. Found have found the problem. It says that the project has Java SE 1.7 as the build path. How can I add the Java SE 8 like yours?

Comment: @MincongHuang Got it! But my question is do I have to do this to each project individually or does it apply to all projects?

Answer (score 0):

Although you have set the compiler settings for Java 8, your project still references the Java 7 System Library in its Build Path (according to the las screen shot in the question, **Edit 3**). You need to select that system library (**JavaSE-1.7**) and use the *Edit...* button to change it to **JavaSE-1.8**) - the one you added in your "Edit 2" update.

In case you're wondering, the difference is between how the compiler produces `.class` files for your code (the **Compiler Compliance** setting) versus the version of the Java standard libraries that are used to compile against (The **JRE System Library**). The two things are separate but usually configured to match each other.

Comment: In "Edit 2", the box is checked off for JavaSE-1.8? Do you mind guiding me via screenshots?

Comment: I said "the last screenshot in the question," where it shows your *project* is still configured to use JavaSE-1.7. You've added a Java 8 library, but you still need to configure that specific project to use it.

Answer (score -1):

It is supported only in Java 8.

Make sure the following are checked:

1. go to your environment variable (start -> type environment variable in search box)
2. make sure your java_home has your bin for jdk 1.8.x version and it is included in your path. (reference you can also look here: [Environment variables for java installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation))

After the environment variable is set restart your eclipse. Undefined should go away.

Comment: Sorry but where is the environment variable? I'm using mac. Do you mind showing via screenshots?

Comment: here is the reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842743/setting-java-home-environment-variable-on-mac-osx-10-9

Comment: This answer is completely wrong for Eclipse; Eclipse doesn't use the JAVA_HOME or other environment variables.